# Controlling socket data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, metadata

Is there anyway to provide any sense of control or ownership over socket data?

I’m looking to add tags or at least have some reference to the file descriptor of the socket where the data came from in order to map it to a specific port. Is there any way to add tags/metadata, or have some sort of identifier which can differentiate data that comes from socket A from data that comes from socket B?

Comment: Read the data into application objects that contain the metadata you want.

Comment: Would that be possible? The issue is I am parsing the data into numpy arrays after it comes from the sockets, which might negate using an object to contain the data. I will keep this in mind regardless, thank you!

Comment: You could put the metadata in another column of the array.